# Python docx - find and replace words with italicized version

Tags: python, python-docx

I have thought of a few ways to accomplish this, but each is uglier than the next. I'm trying to think of a way to search for all instances of a word in a word document and italicize them.

I can't upload a word document, but here's what I had in mind:

[image]

A working example would find all instances of `billybob`, including the one in the table, and italicize them. The problem is the way the runs are frequently aligned means that one run might have `billy` and the next one might have `bob` so there's no straightforward way to find all of them.

Comment: You can check that the next `run` contains `bob` or previous `billy` and set both italicize.

Comment: @Viewed that would only work for that one use case. It's entirely possible for a single word to be split over 20 runs if you did something wonky like alternate between italicized and capitals.

Comment: Well.. Try to make word with some runs and compare to target `bob` or `billy`. Maybe read all text and create new docx with target format?

Comment: The general approach would be to find the word (and its starting offset) from `paragraph.text`, then iterate through the runs until you count up to the first character, then split the run there, then keep going until you pass the last character and split that run there, then italicize all the runs containing the matched pattern. As you indicate, it's not simple. Reminds me of an algorithm interview question :) Note some of these operations (like splitting runs) are not directly supported by the API, so you would need to do some fiddling with the underlying XML.

Comment: @scanny that's basically what I ended up doing. I guess I could post what I did as an answer, but it won't handle the table correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave this open because the approach I came up with isn't perfect, but it works in the vast majority of the cases. Here is the code:

```
document = Document(<YOUR_DOC>)

# Data will be a list of rows represented as dictionaries
# containing each row's data.
characters = {}

for paragraph in <YOUR_PARAGRAPHS>:

    run_string = ""
    run_index = {}
    i = 0

    for x, run in enumerate(paragraph.runs):

        # Create a string consisting of all the runs' text. Theoretically this
        # should always be the same as parapgrah.text, but I didn't check
        run_string = run_string + run.text

        # The index i represents the starting position of the run in question
        # within the string. We are creating a dictionary of form
        # {<run_start_location>: <pointer_to_run>}
        run_index[i] = x

        # This will be the start of the next run
        i = i + len(run.text)

    word_you_wanted_to_find = re.findall("some_regex", paragraph.text)

    for word in word_you_wanted_to_find:

        # [m.start() for m in re.finditer(word, run_string)] returns the starting
        # positions of each word that was found
        for word_start in [m.start() for m in re.finditer(word, run_string)]:
            word_end = word_start + len(word)

            # This will be a list of the indices of the runs which have part
            # of the word we want to include
            included_runs = []

            for key in run_index.keys():

                # Remember, the key is the location in the string of the start of
                # the run. In this case, the start of the word start should be less than
                # the key+len(run) and the end of the word should be greater
                # than the key (the start of the run)
                if word_start <= (key + len(paragraph.runs[run_index[key]].text)) and key < word_end:
                    included_runs.append(key)

                # If the key is larger than or equal to the end of the word,
                # this means we have found all relevant keys. We don't need
                # to loop over the rest (we could, it just wouldn't be efficient)
                if key >= word_end:
                    break

            # At this point, included_runs is a full list of indices to the relevant
            # runs so we can modify each one in turn.
            for run_key in included_runs:
                paragraph.runs[run_index[run_key]].italic = True

document.save(<MODIFIED_DOC>)
```

### Problem 1

The problem with this approach is that, while uncommon (at least in my doc), it is possible for a single run to contain more than just your target word. So you might end up italicizing an entire run that includes your run and then some. For my use case it didn't make sense to fix that problem here.

### Solution

If you were to perfect what I did above you would have to change this code block:

```
if word_start <= (key + len(paragraph.runs[run_index[key]].text)) and key < word_end:
  included_runs.append(key)
```

Here you have identified the run that has your word. You would need to extend the code to separate the word into its own run and remove it from the current run. Then you could separately italicize that run.

### Problem 2

The code shown above doesn't handle both the table and normal text. I didn't need to for my use case, but in the general case you would have to check both.